# Gemspec dependencies are not loaded with Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

For example, given Gemspec file:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require "github_stats/version"

# Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "github_stats"
  s.version     = GithubStats::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["Pura Dawid"]
  s.email       = ["puradawid@gmail.com"]
  s.homepage    = "https://github.com/puradawid/github_stats"
  s.summary     = "Project repository model wrapper and statistic fetcher."
  s.description = ""
  s.license     = "MIT"

  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]
  s.test_files = Dir["test/**/*"]

  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.1.8"
  s.add_runtime_dependency "github_api", "0.12.3"

  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
end
```

And Gemfile for Gods sake:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Declare your gem's dependencies in github_stats.gemspec.
# Bundler will treat runtime dependencies like base dependencies, and
# development dependencies will be added by default to the :development group.
gemspec

# Declare any dependencies that are still in development here instead of in
# your gemspec. These might include edge Rails or gems from your path or
# Git. Remember to move these dependencies to your gemspec before releasing
# your gem to rubygems.org.

# To use a debugger
#gem 'byebug', group: [:development, :test]

#gem 'github_api', '0.12.3'

group :development do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rake'
end
```

`github_api` is commented out (it working obviously if i put it here).

As you can see, github_api is added as a dependency (it's a gem). Is it working? Of course not. Typing a `Bundler.require` gives me:

```
[<Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="github_stats" requirements=">= 0">,
<Bundler::Dependency type=:development name="sqlite3" requirements=">= 0">,
<Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="byebug" requirements=">= 0">,
<Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="mocha" requirements=">= 0">,
<Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="guard" requirements=">= 0">,
<Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="guard-minitest" requirements=">= 0">,
<Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="rake" requirements=">= 0">]
```

I saw this issue [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1096), but i don't see a clean solution.

What is wrong with me? `add_dependency` is not working as well `add_development_dependency` but the last one make no sense here at all, even though i tried it too.

```
 Bundler version 1.8.4
 => ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
```

Thanks for help, folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested - [issue 1041](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1041). After reading it I come to the understanding, that is standard behaviour. The argument is that relying on bundler to require your gem dependencies is a bad practice. You should require your gems explicitly because your gem is supposed to work without bundler. Bundler is widely used but not a standard like ruby gems.

In case you still need some access to the gems needed by bundler you can use this hack:

```
Bundler.definition.specs # gives all gems' dependencies
```

Comment: Thanks! To summarize it: **dependencies defined in gemspec file won't be ever required automatically**. Thanks @hakcho!